# 約 得 recognition and translation

Tags: translation, kanji

[image]
I've got a problem with translation of #8 and #9. I'm not confident if recognised #9 correctly and if these kanji go together of separately.

They may mean "Seems like understood" but please correct me if I'n wrong.

Comment: oh you mean 8 and 9, I will delete my comment, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You recognized #8 correctly, but #9 is actually 納.

The word is read [納得{なっとく}](http://jisho.org/word/%E7%B4%8D%E5%BE%97) and I think it's something close to a "sound effect" of the character realizing that somebody knew 和重 (Kazushige?).

Comment: Not really a sound effect, but something more closer to what a "light bulb" means in western comics, I'd say; an "a-ha".

Comment: @Jimmy Yeah, I quoted sound effect lacking a better term for it. That's a better way to put it